# Generating a lambda by passing in a property name for use in .Count() with Where condition

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression

I'm trying to generate a lambda expression, by passing in the property name to filter on as a string. I then need to count the results where An Enum is set to a certain status

Here's what I've got so far

```
var expressionParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof (ArtworkPage), "page");
var body = Expression.Property(expressionParam, property);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(body, expressionParam,).Compile();

int approvedList = GetArtworkUploadPages(artwork.Id).Count(lambda);
```

How do i get the final piece of the puzzle in passing what enum value i want to filter by into the lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you need the int value of your enum (which maybe wrong)

As `Enumerable.Count()` can take a `Func<T, bool`> as argument :

```
var enumIntValue = Convert.ToInt32(enumValue);

var expressionParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof (ArtworkPage), "page");
Expression body = Expression.Property(expressionParam, property);
body = Expression.Equal(body, Expression.Constant(enumIntValue));
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<ArtworkPage, bool>>(body, expressionParam).Compile();
```

Comment: Cheers, I get a complier error on the body = Expression.Equal line

Comment: Cannot convert source type System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression to target type System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression

Comment: @Doozer1979 edited : replace `var body` by `Expression body`.

Comment: @Doozer1979 by the way, you can shorten all that in one, as shown in SLaks's answer (I think you would just need the conversion to int value)... I made a step by step version, as I think it's easier to understand, but that's the same at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the property with a constant value:

```
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<ArtworkPage, bool>>(
    Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Property(expressionParam, property),
        Expression.Constant(yourEnumValue)
    ),
    experssionParam
);
```